# Getting GWC error trying to enable WMTS capabilities

Tags: geoserver, wmts

I keep getting an error stated as

> Could not locate a layer or layer group with id
> LayerInfoImpl-4bf8d3c8:17b181cff38:-7f87 within GeoServer
> configuration, the GWC configuration seems to be out of synch

when trying to enable WMTS.

What could be the cause?

Comment: could your GeoServer and GWC configurations be out of synch? It usually means that a style is missing

Comment: In my case, I'm sure they ARE out of sync, but I can't find any instructions for resetting the GWC config